# Library (or libraries) for translating REST queries to database queries?

Tags: sql, web-services, rest, clojure, korma

I want to use clojure to build a web service with a RESTful API that exposes resources stored in a relational database (mysql in this case). I'd like to use a library that, given a specification of the db schema, would translate incoming requests to db queries, or korma constructs.

Examples might be:

`GET /users?status=4`

translates to something like:

`` SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `status` = 4; ``

or:

`PUT /users/12`

would be:

`` UPDATE `users` SET ... WHERE `id` = 12 ``

Is there anything out there that would facilitate this?

Comment: If you are just looking for REST libraries to copy from, take a look at github.com/cmiles74/bishop and clojure-liberator.github.io/liberator . Although, from your example compojure and honeysql would be a good fit. Your question on the clojure google group might get a better answer.

Comment: Please don't vandalize your posts. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

In your service, you can get a map that contains:

```
{:uri "/users" :query-params {:status 4}}
```

Or something similar, at least.  From there, you could use either [honey sql](https://github.com/jkk/honeysql) or the DSL in [clojure.java.jdbc](https://github.com/clojure/java.jdbc).

There's no library I know of that goes from request map to sql query directly, though really we're only talking about a few lines of code to do what you're looking for.

What you're asking for isn't flexible or extensible.  What if you need to move a table to a different schema?  What if the url should change?  What should happen if someone puts in bad query params?  How easy is it to expose a new table? etc.

There's too many application specific decisions for this to be reasonably accomplished in a library.